# The difference between top goalscorer and golden boot winner

Tags: football, terminology, scoring, awards

My bookmaker has prices for the golden boot winner and the top tournament goal scorer in the World Cup. What is the difference between the two awards?

Answer (score 13):

There could be multiple top goal scorers, but there can only be one Golden Boot winner. Multiple players could score the most amount of goals, but only one will be awarded the Golden Boot. If there is a tie, the player who has the most number of assists will be awarded the Golden Boot. If there is still a tie, then the player who has played the least amount of time will be awarded the trophy.

Source: [Wikipedia - World Cup Golden Boot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Cup_Golden_Boot#Golden_Boot)

Comment: but 1994 there was 2 golden boot winners

Comment: Seems like FIFA didn't have tie breaker rule before then, and awarded the trophy to multiple players. 1994 was the first multiple players score the most goals.
In 2010 4 players tied for the most goals (each scoring 5 each), the trophy went to Thomas Muller of Germany since he has 3 assists, while the remaining three has one assist each.

Comment: As far as I know, the tie breaker rule was introduced for the 2010 World Cup.

Answer (score -1):

In all short tournaments like WC, Copa or Euro, Godenboot prize is handed to the player who scored most goals in that tournament regardless his form, performance or number of games played. Hence Goldenboot = topscorer no difference.

Since WC82, FIFA introduced another award - GoldenBall to pinpoint the best performer in the tourney and to differentiate with the existing Goldenboot (or just Topscorer)

Comment: A player can be a top scorer but not receive the Golden Boot. Saying they are the same thing is factually wrong.

Comment: You have to add some sources to confirm your answer